# Implementing notifications in between JSON RPC request and response

Tags: c#, json-rpc

As per specification, JSON-RPC allows 3 different messages ie request, response and notification, where a response is provided for every request.

Is it then possible to implement notifications in between a response and a request?

```
--> data sent to service
<-- data coming from service

--> {"method": "startCalculation", "params": [2015], "id": 1} // asynchronous
<-- {"method": "updateProgress", "params": ["10"], "id": null} // 10% done
<-- {"method": "updateProgress", "params": ["50"], "id": null} // 50% done
<-- {"method": "updateProgress", "params": ["100"], "id": null} // 100% done
<-- {"result": 123456, "error": null, "id": 1} // result of startCalculation
```

If it is possible, what are available patterns or models which I can use to implement this in .Net 4.0?

Comment: According to the spec, "A Notification is a Request object without an "id" member. A Request object that is a Notification signifies the Client's lack of interest in the corresponding Response object, and as such no Response object needs to be returned to the client."

So in your example, your notifications are going the wrong way. It would appear that notification are from client to server.

Answer (score 0):

This would be breaking away from the specification.

> The Response is expressed as a single JSON Object

Source: http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#response_object